# Why when I make http request to "imdb.com" I get a 403 Error?

Tags: java, html, http, request, imdb

I want to do like a movie manager. And I wanted to provide my Java Application only the url of the movie on imdb and it automaticly get the producers name and other things.

It's working with other sites, bue with this one, instead of the HTML, I get a Java Error, caught by an exception...the 403 error (forbidden).

Comment: And the traffic sent and received, and the exact error? Perhaps it's because there's a simple user agent check which prevents you from downloading the content, as per their [conditions](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions): _"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."_.

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api

Comment: @CodeCaster  I was about to surf over to IMBD to check their EULA.  <sarcasm>What a surprise they don't want people reusing the data they went to so much trouble to collect and maintain.</sarcasm>

Answer (score 2):

If my prediction is right, imdb checks for browser info, just change your user-agent header, perhaps add a referrer header too, and you will be good to go.

Comment: Can point me a question where is teached to do that?
I can't find anything useful at first...

Comment: which library are you using for HTTP access?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480153/how-to-modify-the-header-of-a-httpurlconnection

Answer (score 1):

> 403 error (forbidden)

Forbidden means "You're not allowed to do that".  I don't know what answer you expected to get beyond "**Don't** do that".

Comment: What is I want to web-scrape with python, and I use requests.get and get the same message. It means that it is forbidden for me to do that? Is it illegal?