# Converting CURL request to HTTP Request Java

Tags: java, curl

I have the following CURL request Can anyone please confirm me what would be the subesquest HTTP Request

```
      curl -u "Login-dummy:password-dummy" -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" "https://qualysapi.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/report/?action=list" -k
```

Will it be something like ?

```
    String url = "https://qualysapi.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/report/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET"); ..... //incomplete
```

Can anyone be kind enough to help me convert the above curl request completely to httpreq.

Thanks in advance.

Suvi

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve this. Below one is simplest in my opinion, Agree it isn't very flexible but works.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class HttpClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String stringUrl = "https://qualysapi.qualys.eu/api/2.0/fo/report/?action=list";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        uc.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");

        String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
        // read this input

    }
}
```

Comment: You can add maven dependency for org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 from here :


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether `HttpURLConnection` is your best friend here. I think [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is a better option here.

Just in case you must use `HttpURLConnection`, you can try this links:

You are setting username/password, a HTTP-Header option and ignore SSL certificate validation.

- How to set username/password check this thread: [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java)
- How to set eader options have a look at this thread: [How to modify the header of a HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480153/how-to-modify-the-header-of-a-httpurlconnection)
- How to ignore SSL certificate validation is described here http://www.obsidianscheduler.com/blog/ignoring-self-signed-certificates-in-java .

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Below worked for me:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator("user@account","password"));

-------
public MyAuthenticator(String user, String passwd){
    username=user;
    password=passwd;
}
```