# How to formulate curl -XHEAD request in java

Tags: java, http, url, curl, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch Java API and trying to make a curl call in order to find out whether a document exists in my index or not. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-exists.html) is how it is done in the command line. As far as I can tell from the posts here, I should either use HttpURLConnection java class or apache httpclient to send the curl request in java. 
My request should be like :

`curl -i -XHEAD http://localhost:9200/indexName/mappingName/docID`.

There are actually many questions on how to send curl requests via java, but the answers are not that explanatory - thus I am not sure how to configure the request parameters for the curl head request. So far, I have reproduced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636567/converting-curl-request-to-http-request-java) answer from Ashay and it doesn't work.

Does anybody send curl calls in elasticsearch's java API and can explain how to do it?

Here is my code and the error I get is "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol"

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(new StringBuilder()
    .append("http://").append(serverName).append(":9200/") // elasticsearch port
    .append(indexName).append("/").append(mappingName).append("/")
    .append(url).toString(), "UTF-8"); // docID is a url
System.out.print("encodedURL : " + encodedURL + "\n");

URL url = new URL(new StringBuilder().append(encodedURL).toString());
System.out.print("url "+ url.toString() + "\n");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

String userpass = new StringBuilder().append(username).append(":").append(password).toString();
String basicAuth = new StringBuilder().append("Basic ").append(new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()))).toString();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
String inputLine;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

P.S. the document ids of this index are urls and that is why I need to encode them. On the other hand, I am not sure whether I should encode the full http request or not.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet could be a starting point.

```
String serverName = "localhost";
String indexName = "index_name";
String mappingName = "mapping_name";
String docId = "FooBarId";

String username = "JohnDoe";
String password = "secret";

String requestURL = String.format("http://%s:9200/%s/%s/%s",
        serverName,
        indexName,
        mappingName,
        docId
);
System.out.println("requestURL: " + requestURL);

URL url = new URL(requestURL);
System.out.println("URL: " + url);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

String credentials = username + ":" + password;

Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
String basicAuth = "Basic " + encoder.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

connection.getHeaderFields()
        .entrySet()
        .forEach((Entry<String, List<String>> t) -> {
            System.out.printf("%-20s : %s%n", t.getKey(), t.getValue());
        });
```

Using `requestURL = "http://localhost:9200";` with a default elasticsearch installation would return

```
requestURL: http://localhost:9200
URL: http://localhost:9200
null                 : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Content-Length       : [0]
Content-Type         : [text/plain; charset=UTF-8]
```

**add** Maybe you can try something similar to following steps. Amend them to your needs. Maybe you can skip the first step.

**index something**

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/books/book/1" -d'
{
    "title": "The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy",
    "author": "Douglas Adams",
    "year": 1978
}'
```

**query it from commandline**

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/books/book/1
```

output

```
{"_index":"books","_type":"book","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":
{
    "title": "The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy",
    "author": "Douglas Adams",
    "year": 1978
}}
```

**query using the above Java snippet**

```
String serverName = "localhost";
String indexName = "books";
String mappingName = "book";
String docId = "1";
String requestURL = String.format("http://%s:9200/%s/%s/%s",
        serverName,
        indexName,
        mappingName,
        docId
);
System.out.println("requestURL: " + requestURL);
URL url = new URL(requestURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.getHeaderFields()
        .entrySet()
        .forEach((Entry<String, List<String>> t) -> {
            System.out.printf("%-20s : %s%n", t.getKey(), t.getValue());
        });
try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
    for (int i = inputStream.read(); i > -1; i = inputStream.read()) {
        System.out.print((char) i);
    }
}
```

output

```
requestURL: http://localhost:9200/books/book/1
null                 : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Content-Length       : [184]
Content-Type         : [application/json; charset=UTF-8]
{"_index":"books","_type":"book","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":
{
    "title": "The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy",
    "author": "Douglas Adams",
    "year": 1978
}}
```

The example use a default elasticsearch installation.

Depending on what you really want to achieve. You might be better use the elasticsearch `TransportClient`.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;

public class GetDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        InetSocketTransportAddress socketAddr =
                new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostAddr, 9300);
        try (Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
                .addTransportAddress(socketAddr)) {
            GetRequestBuilder request = client.prepareGet("books", "book", "1");
            GetResponse response = request.execute().actionGet();
            response.getSource()
                    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%-6s: %s%n", k, v));
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
...
year  : 1978
author: Douglas Adams
title : The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your example code yields a "null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] Content-Length=[145] Content-Type=[text/plain; charset=UTF-8]" error for all docIds. The only changes I made were to replace localhost with our server name and also use "Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes());" because Base64.Encoder is private

Comment: @KonstantinaLazaridou [Base64.Encoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) is a `public static class` in Java 8. Have you checked your generated `url`and the `basicAuth`? As `HTTP 400` is for `The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.`

Comment: yes, the url seems fine and the user info are also correct. Is it possible that the server uses different encryption system than Base64? I also commended the authorization property (in case it was not necessary), but still the same error. I also don't know whether `.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");` is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Try to break down the problem. **1)** Enter the url you want to access in a browser. **a)** Is the url valid. **b)** Do you get a request pop-up for user/password. **2)** If the url is working assign it as a fixed string to `requestURL` in the above example. Another question is your curl example working without an user/password? If so. Why do you believe you need it in the java code?